# Average of numbers in two consequetive sequences using Matlab

Tags: matlab, sequence, average, rows, skip

I have an array that is 13867 X 2 elements and stored in variable called "data". So, I want to do the following in Matlab:

- Average (row 1 -> row 21) ; i.e. take the average of first 21 elements
- Average (row 22 -> row 43) ; i.e. take the average of next 22 elements
- Average (row 44 -> row 64); i.e. take the average of the next 21 elements
- Average (row 65 -> row 86); i.e. take the average of the next 22 elements
- Repeat the process until the end of the matrix, so that we take the average of the last 21 elements from row 13847 to row 13876. I want the average of elements in column 1 and also column 2. I have somehow managed to do that in Excel, but it is a bit cumbersome task (had to create an index for the rows first). I guess at the end we will get 645 averages.

Comment: My thought process after reading this question: 1. Think of obvious ways to do it using loops. 2. Try to figure out how I could vectorize it (would be very simple if they were all 21 or 22 elements). 3. Give up after 2 minutes since I guess someone will come up with a clever vectorized way to do this, leaving my loopy answers to rot =P

Comment: As it stands now this is a very low effort question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to doing that is inserting `NaN` rows to make the shorter blocks (21 rows) the same size as the longer blocks (22 rows). This is very easy, using the `insertrows` function from [Matlab FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9984-insertrows--v2-0--may-2008-):

```
n = 21;
m = 22;

dataPad = insertrows(data, nan(1,size(data,2)), n:(n+m):size(data,1));
```

After that, row 22 will be `[NaN, NaN]`, row 66 will be `[NaN, NaN]`, and so on. Now it gets very easy to calculate the mean. Simply reshape this matrix so that all values which should be averaged are on the same column. Finally, use the [`nanmean`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) function (mean function which simply ignores `NaN`) to get the result.

It is not 100% clear to me, whether the result should be 645x2 or 645x1, i.e. whether to average over the rows as well, or not. Here would be the corresponding `reshape`'s for both ways:

**1.** Averaging over the rows too:

```
dataPadRearr = reshape(dataPad.',m*size(data,2),[]);
result = nanmean(dataPadRearr,1);
```

**2.** Leaving the rows alone:

```
dataPadRearr = reshape(dataPad,m,[],size(data,2));
result = squeeze(nanmean(dataPadRearr,1));
```

Note that here, you'll need a final [`squeeze`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html), as the result of `nanmean` would be of dimension `1x645x2`, which is not very practical. `squeeze` just removes this singleton dimension.

Comment: The code does not produce the results I would expect, I would the first two elements of `result` to be equal to `mean(data(1:21,:))`

Comment: @Daniel I was not 100% sure about that myself. In the question, Emma says that she expects 645 averages, so I went with this way. The only thing that change is the `reshape` though, so I added both ways to the answer.

Comment: @hbaderts Your solution works also very well. and the method used is simple and smart. Thank you!

Comment: @hbaderts oh, the result should be a 645x2 array. Sweet of you to provide answer for both ways :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve it with some padding with `NaNs`, reshaping and concatenations -

```
%// Input
A = rand(13867,2);

%// Two stepsizes
m = 21;
n = 22;

%// Combined stepsize
N = m+n;

%// Pad with NaNs to simplify reshaping & finding averages with nanmean
Apad = cat(1,A,nan(N*ceil(numel(A)/(2*N)) - numel(A)/2,2));

%// Reshape into a 3D array with Combined stepsize number of rows
B = reshape(Apad,N,numel(Apad)/(2*N),[]);

%// Index into first m rows and get nan ignored averages row-wise. 
%// Reshape into rows x 2 sized array
C = reshape(cat(1,nanmean(B(1:m,:,:),1),nanmean(B(m+1:end,:,:),1)),[],2);

%// Ignore NaNs and thus have the final output
out = reshape(C(~isnan(C)),[],2);
```

---

**Verify output**

First five rows -

```
>> out(1:4,:)
ans =
      0.55694      0.55289
      0.49942      0.53502
      0.57768      0.40828
       0.6347      0.45194

>> mean(A(1:21,:),1)
ans =
      0.55694      0.55289
>> mean(A(22:43,:),1)
ans =
      0.49942      0.53502
>> mean(A(44:64,:),1)
ans =
      0.57768      0.40828
>> mean(A(65:86,:),1)
ans =
       0.6347      0.45194
```

Last row -

```
>> out(end,:)
ans =
      0.44631      0.59432
>> mean(A(13847:13867,:),1)
ans =
      0.44631      0.59432
```

---

**Explanation with the help of a toy example**

Sample used -

```
%// Input
A = rand(17,2)

%// Two stepsizes
m = 3;
n = 4;
```

1] Input :

```
A =
      0.64775      0.30635
      0.45092      0.50851
      0.54701      0.51077
      0.29632      0.81763
      0.74469      0.79483
      0.18896      0.64432
      0.68678      0.37861
      0.18351      0.81158
      0.36848      0.53283
      0.62562      0.35073
      0.78023        0.939
     0.081126      0.87594
      0.92939      0.55016
      0.77571      0.62248
      0.48679      0.58704
      0.43586      0.20774
      0.44678      0.30125
```

2] Combine step-size :

```
N =
     7
```

3] Pad with NaN filled rows such that the number of rows is a multiple of `N` -

```
Apad =
      0.64775      0.30635
      0.45092      0.50851
      0.54701      0.51077
      0.29632      0.81763
      0.74469      0.79483
      0.18896      0.64432
      0.68678      0.37861
      0.18351      0.81158
      0.36848      0.53283
      0.62562      0.35073
      0.78023        0.939
     0.081126      0.87594
      0.92939      0.55016
      0.77571      0.62248
      0.48679      0.58704
      0.43586      0.20774
      0.44678      0.30125
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN
```

4] This part might be a bit tricky. Consider each column from `Apad` is made into a 2D array, such that we would have `N` elements per column, because the intention here is to get averages along each column after further slicing each column into two subgroups of first three rows and rest four rows from such a 3D array. So, with `Apad` having 2 rows, we would have a 3D array with two 3D slices, such that the first 3D slice would be a reshaped version of first column in `Apad` i.e. of `Apad(:,1)`. Similarly, the second 3D slice corresponds to the second column in `Apad`. Thus, the ressultant 3D array would be -

```
B(:,:,1) =
      0.64775      0.18351      0.48679
      0.45092      0.36848      0.43586
      0.54701      0.62562      0.44678
      0.29632      0.78023          NaN
      0.74469     0.081126          NaN
      0.18896      0.92939          NaN
      0.68678      0.77571          NaN
B(:,:,2) =
      0.30635      0.81158      0.58704
      0.50851      0.53283      0.20774
      0.51077      0.35073      0.30125
      0.81763        0.939          NaN
      0.79483      0.87594          NaN
      0.64432      0.55016          NaN
      0.37861      0.62248          NaN
```

5] Find mean/average along each column with `nanmean(..,1)` ignoring the `NaNs` -

```
>> nanmean(B(1:m,:,:),1)
ans(:,:,1) =
      0.54856      0.39254      0.45648
ans(:,:,2) =
      0.44188      0.56504      0.36534
>> nanmean(B(m+1:end,:,:),1)
ans(:,:,1) =
      0.47919      0.64161          NaN
ans(:,:,2) =
      0.65885      0.74689          NaN
```

6] Concatenate and reshape those averages into a 2D array -

```
C =
      0.54856      0.44188
      0.47919      0.65885
      0.39254      0.56504
      0.64161      0.74689
      0.45648      0.36534
          NaN          NaN
```

7] Ignore NaN rows for final output -

```
out =
      0.54856      0.44188
      0.47919      0.65885
      0.39254      0.56504
      0.64161      0.74689
      0.45648      0.36534
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and prompt response. You have made my day! It works flawlessly 

I'm a novice in Matlab, so would you please explain in a bit more detail what the code does? :)

Comment: @Emma See if the edits help in understanding the solution. The important and maybe a bit confusing step would be the fourth one, so give that a bit more attention. Glad to have *made your day*! :)

Comment: Really thank you for taking time and effort to explain the solution. Great that you exist guys!

Comment: Hello again, It has been a while! I'm again having some issues with averaging, but now on a more general level. In the question that I asked here I knew in advance how the data is formatted, but it gets really cumbersome if the data is a bit not uniform. Can you please check this question and see if the process can be automated?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598096/averaging-data-that-have-similar-properties-in-matlab
Thank you guys!

Comment: @Emma Been a while indeed! Posted a comment there, give it a try :)